# addthis IE fails display multiple images in facebook sharing

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, addthis, sharethis

I have a web page I want people to share on facebook. So I placed addthis buttons for facebook, twitter ... and added some extra code

```
    <meta og:title ... />
    <meta og:url .../>
    <meta og:image ... /> for each image
```

when I click the button, I can see title, url, site name (derived from url), and an image.
In Chrome, I can choose within multiple images, but not with IE (IE9 under windows7 64bits)
I have the same issue with sharethis.
But when I paste the page url in facebook directly, both IE and Chrome handle it properly.

Is this an issue with adthis and similar social plugin, with IE specifically?
I also tried to run with compatibility mode on and off with the same result.
How can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide a page that I could look at?

Comment: thx for help. My page is on test on a local web server, so I do not have something simple to demonstrate the issue, right now!
I did more test by changing the url with a similar content for 3 or 4 pages, still with addthis widget. I can get all the images in IE, but sometimes I cannot get all.
Before testing, I emptied cookies and cache, check url in facebook linter.
I guess there is a lack of consistancy when using addthis and IE, or a cache problem.